# jquery change event validation stop other actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if this has been answered elsewhere, (apologies if so!)
But...
I have an edit field which is validated on the .change() event.
what I want to do is this:
if the user has mouse-pressed the save button directly after typing, .change() fires first, then the button .click() fires after - I want to prevent the .click() event firing if the entered value doesn't get validated, once the popup has been cleared.

This is an example of what it is doing now, but this still allows other buttons to be pressed.

```
validateRetention(e) {
   if (someCondition) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }    
}
$('input[type="number"]').change(function () {
   if (!validateRetention(this)) {
      alert("bad data entered");
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this an issue? The `change` event will fire on `blur`, which will fire before any `click` event. Clicking the button directly after typing won't change that, `change` will fire first. http://jsbin.com/fahacubasi/edit?js,console,output All you need to do is prevent the form submission, as has been suggested.

Comment: Thats my point. I want the button click event to be blocked if that is what has instigated the blur/change event to fire on the edit field.

Comment: Then Marcos' suggestion is pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent default action:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event)  {
     if(isNotValidForm) {
          event.preventDefault();
          // make validation balloons
     }
});
```